# SSH tunneling puzzle

Tags: ssh, windows-vista, fedora, putty

I am trying to tunnel vnc through putty (on win vista) to an ssh server on fedora 14. Normal vnc connections work but the tunnel just terminates immediately. My server config file:

`VNCSERVERS="2:Robert 3:Christina 4:Lan 5:Simon"
 VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1280x800 -localhost"
 VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1280x800 -localhost"
 VNCSERVERARGS[4]="-geometry 1280x800 -localhost"
 VNCSERVERARGS[5]="-geometry 1024x600 "`

Nothing of significance is being been reported in any of the logs except for the sshd log on the server which prints out one of the following lines: **sshd[8993] error connect_to 192.168.1.64 port 5902: failed** except I'm actually not trying to connect to 5902. whichever port I try to tunnel to gives the same error.

Comment: How is the tunnel configured in Putty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! It turned out that having the having the standard vnc ports forwarded as well as the ssh ports forwarded was causing the issue somehow. (I don't understand how or why at the moment)